# Why not to use Super Wildcard when reading from a collection

Tags: java

In Java, it's said to use "extend wildcard" to read from a data structure and "super wildcard" to put something into it. I can understand the first one, but not the latter.

First one (user extend wildcard to get) is understandable:

```
Class B --extends--> Class A
Class C --extends--> Class A

public static void doSomething(List<? extends A> list, int index) {
    list.set(0, new ClassC());
}
```

while doSomething is called with a list of instances of `classB`. Well... This is wrong and I get it.

But! I don't get the rule for super wildcard. Why is it dangerous to read from a `List<? super A>` ?

I would appreciate if you could give me a example besides defining it. I already read some texts including [Oracle Wildcards](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html).

Comment: wildcards with `super` are for the superclasses of the class instead of the subclasses.

Comment: How are you reading from `list`? Is it `Object o = list.get(0)` or `A o = list.get(0)`? Try it see compile errors.

Comment: When I use `Object` there is not compile error.

Comment: The point is that you cant read `A` from `List<? super A>` safely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to type erasure... what is `<A>`? If wildcard `<?>` is part of the `<A>` family... how could `<A>` be determined? At this point we need `<A super Object>` is undefined. This is a classic targeting issue with type erasure.

Imagine the case:

    `<? extends MyFavoriteTreeOfClasses>`

After complication the compiler and runtime is aware that `<?>` must be part of `Class<MyFavoriteTreeOfClasses>`.

Due to the case presentedwe know we are working in java and the language uses type erasure. Since it is erased when compiled

we know that after complation,  is bound to the scope of  (MyFavoriteTreeOfClasses)... but when dealing with A in a pure erased type this is Object after Compilation... When dealing with left side assignment...

---

```
? extends MyFavoriteTreeOfClasses = Object
```

---

So the lowest form of ? is an interface that is MyFavoriteTreeOfClasses

... since `MyTreeInTheFavorites` extends it... it is NOT `<?>` since Object does not implement `MyFavoriteTreeOfClasses`